# how to find the maximum and its associated values from a grouped relation in pig?

Tags: apache-pig, bigdata

Below is my input

```
$ cat people.csv
Steve,US,M,football,6.5
Alex,US,M,football,5.5
Ted,UK,M,football,6.0
Mary,UK,F,baseball,5.5
Ellen,UK,F,football,5.0
```

I Need to group my data based on the Country.

```
people = LOAD 'people.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray,country:chararray,gender:chararray, sport:chararray,height:float);
grouped = GROUP people BY country;
```

Now i have to find the maximum height of the person and his details from the grouped data.

So i tried the below

```
a = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group AS country, MAX(people.height) as height, people.name as name;
```

which gives the output as

```
(UK,6.0,{(Ellen),(Mary),(Ted)})
(US,6.5,{(Alex),(Steve)})
```

But i need my output should be

```
(UK,6.0,Ted)
(US,6.5,Steve)
```

Could someone please help me to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This code will help you .

As per this code, If there are two players with max height under the same country then you will get both those players details

```
records = LOAD '/home/user/footbal.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(name:chararray,country:chararray,gender:chararray,sport:chararray,height:double);

records_grp  = GROUP records BY (country);

records_each = foreach records_grp generate group as temp_country, MAX(records.height) as max_height;

records_join = join records by (country,height), records_each by (temp_country,max_height);

records_output = foreach records_join generate country, max_height, name;

dump records_output;
```

OutPut :

```
(UK,6.0,Ted)
(US,6.5,Steve)
```